# Use COUNTIF inside INDIRECT in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to reference a range in a google sheet based on counting the number of not-empty rows in a different column.

I basically want to look up `'Jens Raw Data'!K:Kx`, where `x` is the number of the last not empty row in column J. This is what I have tried:

```
=indirect("Jens Raw Data'!K"&COUNTIF('Jens Raw Data'!J:J,"<>"))
```

I get this error: Function `INDIRECT` parameter 1 value is `'Jens Raw Data'!K:K91'`. It is not a valid cell/range reference.

Putting a `TEXT` around the countif did not work (or I could not figure out how to do it properly).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You forgot the leading `'` before `Jens Raw Data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference strings on INDIRECT should not use `'`, so instead of

```
=indirect("Jens Raw Data'!K"&COUNTIF('Jens Raw Data'!J:J,"<>"))
```

try

```
=indirect("Jens Raw Data!K"&COUNTIF('Jens Raw Data'!J:J,"<>"))
```